# Set outer index as column in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a data frame that's in the following sort of format (I unfortunately cannot share the actual dataframe:

```
      1                     10                  20 
      Ripeness  Tastinesss  Ripeness Tastiness Ripeness Tastiness 
Apple   4          10        ......

Banana  6          5         ......

Pear    3          5        ......
```

Call the outer index "source". What I want to produce is something of this form

```
          Ripeness Tastiness Source
Apple       4         10        1 
Banana      6          5        1 
Pear        3          5        1 
Apple       ....     ...       10 
Banana      ....     ...       10 
Pear        ....     ...       10 
Apple       ....     ...       20 
Banana      ....     ...       20 
Pear        ....     ...       20
```

I've tried a lot of different ways at this point and I have no idea how to do this. It seems quite simple though - can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Stack to reshape

```
df.stack().rename_axis([None, 'Source']).reset_index(level=1)
```